# MQTT How to know the Broker Status

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

In a web application with MQTT in python (using paho-mqtt lib) I would like to know if there is a way to get the broker status in real time, because the only way that i find is to store the variable "rc" into the method on_connect but it's more like a client/connection state.

EDIT 1 : after reading mosquitto broker documentation, i found that you can subscribe to `'$SYS/broker/connection/#'` which is supposed to give you back 1 if the connection is up and 0 if it goes down. However when i do :

```
subscribe.callback(self.message_callback, '$SYS/broker/connection/#', port = port, hostname=broker, auth=authentication, protocol=client.MQTTv31, tls=TLS)
```

impossible to get payload and topic this message  although i'm doing exactly the same command to get messages from my sensors except that the topic is `'#'` and it's working perfectly.

Does anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to poll the state of the connection to the broker from the client.

The `on_disconnect` callback should be called when the connection to the broker is dropped.

This should be kicked off when the keep alive times out, but also as the result of a failure to publish (if you try to publish data before the timeout expires).

Also the `rc` from a call to the [publish](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#publish) command will indicate if the connection has dropped.

Comment: That is for mqtt bridge connections, not client connections, also if the broker is down how is it supposed to deliver that message?

Comment: okay that makes sense that's what i was asking to myself do you know if there is another topic which could do the trick ? Because i'm not using any client, just a subscribe to the broker to get messages and then store them into a database.

Comment: No, my answer is correct, there is no topic you could possibly subscribe to that will tell you the state of the broker. And you are using a client.

Comment: okay thank you for your help. You're saying that i am using a client but i never declare it, i have no method on_connect or on_message that i bind on the callbacks functions. can you explain me more about this ? (sorry i just arrived on this project at work and i'm pretty not familiar with it yet)

Comment: You are using the wrapped `simple.subscribe` client, if you want to know about the state of the broker you will have to move to the full client to set a `on_disconnect` callback